# CSS border-bottom getting space between elements

Tags: html, css

I am working on a sidebar, where I have 'a' elements inside 'li's, applying CSS code on them, and giving them border. However when I apply border-bottom on the 'a' elements, space between the elements is also effected. How can I remove this space between them? Thanks.

Sidebar image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xUp2.jpg

Code [html] :

```
<div id="container">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li><a href="#" class="selected">Dashboard</li>
                <li><a href="#">Booter Hub</li>
                <li><a href="#">Stresser</li>
                <li><a href="#">Friends</li>
                <li><a href="#">Search</li>
                <li><a href="#">Purchase</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
```

Code [CSS] :

```
ul#nav li a {
color: #ccc;
display: block;
padding: 10px;
font-size: 0.8em;
border-bottom: 1px solid #0A0A0A;
-webkit-transition: 0.2s;
-moz-transition: 0.2s;
-o-transition: 0.2s;
transition: 0.2s
```

}

Comment: box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: Close your `<a>` tags...

Comment: Can you add the CSS for #container and #sidebar as well ?

Comment: Could you place your code within a working fiddle instead of linking to an image otherwise no way to replicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing.. Close that `a` tag...

```
<li><a href="#" class="selected">Dashboard</a></li>
```

Once you have done that you will get the following result (I have removed the `ul` `list-style`, `margin` and `padding`, I am assuming you have done the same in other code not shared in the question)...

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#nav li a {
  border: 1px solid pink;
}

#nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ccc;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0A0A0A;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <ul id="nav">
              <li><a href="#" class="selected">Dashboard</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Booter Hub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Stresser</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Purchase</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
```

*remember to add `text-decoration: none;` to remove the default `a` tag underline.

Comment: wow that was really dumb hah...yes that was the problem. Thanks and sorry for the banality of this question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be a bit careful here.  First, zero out the margin and padding for the parent `ul` element (which will also zero out the same for the `li` child elements).

You can then add the styling to the `a` elements as you need for your design.

```css
#nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#nav li {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
#nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  background-color: beige;
)
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#" class="selected">Dashboard</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Booter Hub</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Stresser</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Purchase</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You request is unclear but it **sounds** as though you are suggesting that adding the border increases the height of the elements.

To have the borders/padding be included in the overall element dimensions you can use the `box-sizing:border-box` css property.

> The box-sizing property is used to alter the default CSS box model used to calculate widths and heights of elements. It is possible to use this property to emulate the behavior of browsers that do not correctly support the CSS box model specification.

**Examples**

```
box-sizing: content-box;
box-sizing: padding-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: inherit;
```

***border-box***

> The width and height properties include the padding and border, but not the margin. This is the box model used by Internet Explorer when the document is in Quirks mode. Note: Padding & border will be inside of the box e.g. IF .box {width: 350px}; THEN you apply {border: 10px solid black;} RESULT {rendered in the browser} .box {width: 350px;}

[**Box-sizing @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Comment: I think the OP was also triggering a collapsing margin effect, adding the bottom border would prevent margins collapsing around the `a` and `li` elements.